# Calling InitializeComponent() twice in constructor

Tags: c#, .net

So I made a simple class derived by `Form` with a `ComboBox` and a `Button`.

In that class's constructor `InitializeComponent()` gets fired twice as follow.
(Just for study purpose)

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     InitializeComponent(); // One more time
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text);
}
```

Then whatever items in the `comboBox1` I click, `comboBox1.Text` is always `String.Empty`.

The only way to solve this problem seems to call `comboBox1.Dispose()` between the 2 `InitializeComponent()`, and I would like to know why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically `InitializeComponent` isn't *designed* to be executed more than once. I suspect there are subtle issues around which order you created the controls in which would affect this, but the simple solution is not to do it. I don't think you'll actually gain any useful information from looking into this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `InitializeComponents` in `Form1.Designer.cs`.

If you call it twice, you'll have two Combobox's. One may be the visible on that you can edit. The other one (the second) is the one that your code refers to.

You could "prove" it by introducing a static field called `Counter`. Then edit the `InitializeComponent` slightly, such that it moves the ComboBox a bit depending on `Counter` and set `ComboBox.Tag` to `Counter`. Finally, increment `Counter`.

However, as you'll surely notice, this is only a problem of academic relevance. There's no benefit in calling `InitializeComponents` twice.